# Modifying the environment for a child process in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, ipc

I'm not sure why this isn't working, but perhaps I've oversimplified/overcomplicated things

I'm writing a Perl script that ultimately needs to call an external program. The catch is, this program needs a modified version of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, in order to find a couple of libraries which the vendor does not install in standard places.

OK, the environment is in `%ENV`, which can be rewritten, yes?

I thought if I changed `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the parent, it would affect the dynamic linking of the child.

So I have:

```
use Env qw(@LD_LIBRARY_PATH);
use IPC::System::Simple qw(capturex $EXITVAL);

# We need these to establish the call to rsq later
my ($rsqexe, $rsqhome, $suffix) = fileparse($config->rsq());
push @LD_LIBRARY_PATH, $rsqhome;

eval {
  $output = capturex(
    $config->rsq(),
    qq/"$source"/
  );
};
```

But the child process dies with an error indicating the shared libraries can't be found.

How can I improve this?

I do need to examine the contents of `$output` after successful execution.

Comment: Try wrapping the program you're trying to execute with a wrapper that dumps the contents of $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Divide the unknown problem into two halfs. If you're not seeing the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH that you expect to see, you can look in one direction. If you're seeing the right $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but your wrapper can't execute the program anyway, you'll then look into a different direction.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - your approach uncovered the real problem (which wasn't with LD_LIBRARY_PATH at all, after all that)

Answer (score 1):

```
    eval {
      $output = capturex(
        $config->rsq(),
        qq/"$source"/
      );
    };
```

Here's the problem: I wasn't examining what was in `$@` (or `$EVAL_ERR` if you `use ENGLISH;`)

If I had, I would have seen that the problem was with the quoting `qq/"$source"/` - because `capturex()` **doesn't** call the shell (which was the desired behaviour) the quotes break the file name (i.e. `test.pdf` exists, but `""test.pdf""` does not).

Comment: Right, should just be `capturex($config->rsq(), $source)`. The whole point of using `capturex` is to avoid using `shell_quote` or very buggy quoting solutions like `qq/"$source"/`.